# Rails Admin Datepicker...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I'm using `rails_admin` (with not much extra configuration). I have been reading for some time and it's quite frustrating, I can't find out how to activate the simple datepicker that's used right IN the demo.

http://rails-admin-tb.herokuapp.com/admin/field_test/new

Look down towards the date field.

The only thing I have found is the demo's source code which has nothing I can find related to a date picker.

There's also one page of the wiki which is very vague, and mentions a gem which isn't even used in the demo's source code.

How can I just implement this in this simple bit of code for `created_at`?

```
  config.model 'Comment' do
    list do
      field :user
      field :body
      field :flags
      field :created_at
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this buried in an issue. I can't be bothered to go back and look if they actually said to use this... but I can't believe it wasn't stated better how to do this so simply.

Just use the `configure` block instead, like this...

```
  config.model 'Video' do
    list do
      field :title
      field :youtube_id
      field :views
      field :description
    end
    configure :created_at do
      show
    end
  end
```